Force pages to re-render (Next.js App-Dir)
For this question I have created the following demo Next.js application using the App directory:

It has a standard RootLayout in app/layout.tsx.
It has a nested Layout in a route group app/(app)/layout.tsx. This layout contains <nav />.
It has two server-side rendered pages: app/(app)/a/page.tsx and app/(app)/b/page.tsx.
Each page calls getCurrentTime() (defined on app/functions.ts) and then display the render time.

I want each navigation to a page to cause a re-render and run getCurrentTime() again, but I couldn't make the pages not cache. I've tried adding both export const revalidate = 0 and export const dynamic = "force-dynamic" (docs), but couldn't make it work.
I’m sure it’s pretty basic, but I still couldn’t get the hang of it.
View on StackBlitz


I would just move time to a client component
"use client";

import { getCurrentTime } from "@/app/functions";

export const Time = (): JSX.Element => {
  return <span>{getCurrentTime()}</span>;
};

Check out related topic How can I disable cache on a specific page only in Next.JS

Thanks for the suggestion! I simplified my problem to getCurrentTime() just to illustrate my question. In my real project, this function must run on the server since it will be used to query the database. I could though move this logic to an API route and then fetch it via client component as you said.

You welcome, code in server components run once, API route seems like the best approach so far.

According to the Next.js docs, seems like the mechanism responsible for caching pages on the client is the Router Cache and its purpose is to reduce server requests on navigation (source).
The documentation says: (source)

Opting Out ‒ It's not possible to opt out of the Router Cache. However, you can invalidate it by calling router.refresh, revalidatePath, or revalidateTag . This will clear the cache and make a new request to the server, ensuring the latest data is shown.

Since revalidatePath and revalidateTag can only be used in a server action, I ended with this creating a pseudo client component that will refresh the page on any navigation to it.
It's not the prettiest solution but it works.
"use client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Refresh = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const InitialPathname = useRef(pathname);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (InitialPathname.current === pathname) return;
    router.refresh();
  }, [router, pathname]);
  return null;
};

export default Refresh;

